# How can you make it automatically invisible to render if its already invisible in viewport?

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

The objects i make invisible in viewport i want them to automatically be invisible to render. Is there any cool way to have this option ?

Comment: I  do not know of a cool way, but you can click the camera icon in the outliner.

Comment: That i know, but when you have too many objects, you need to go through all.
Was wondering if there was some option or python script

Comment: `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].hide_render = True`

Comment: Select every visible objects by pressing "A" then hit "W" and select "Restrict Render Unselected"

Comment: @FFeller this doesnt seem to work on blender 2.8, nothing comes up after pressin W

Comment: @rob thats awesome, but only hides the one mesh with the name you put in the brackets... "cube" but not the other ones....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Handlers**

Could set in a handler. `bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_[pre or post]` are the v2.8x equivalent of scene update in versions prior.

Run this script once. Now every time the depsgraph updates ( a lot ) it will match the hide render attribute to the objects hide status.

```
import bpy

def hide(scene):
    for o in scene.objects:
        o.hide_render = o.hide_get()

    return None

# uncomment to clear all
#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(hide)
```

Comment: Great!  !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This code when run will hide all the selected objects from being rendered

```
import bpy 

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects 

for obj in selection: 
    bpy.data.objects[obj.name].hide_render = True
```

It also make sense if you are doing this a lot to change the functionality to *toggle*.
This version will *toggle* the render visibility of all the selected objects

```
import bpy 

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects 

for obj in selection: 
    obj.hide_render = not obj.hide_render
```

Comment: thanks @batFINGER, updated

Comment: In 2.79 version we could move the selected objects to some other layer and leave that layer hidden. Could it be a similar way to do it in 2.8? Unfortunately, I can't use the 2.8 version yet.